# Fixed width table with variable columns

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I've got a fixed width table ( `style="width: 100%"` ) with dynamic data being placed into the cells.  The data varies greatly in terms of width, and some strings exceed the length of the table without spaces.  Therefore, I've used `table { table-layout:fixed; word-wrap: break-word; }` to wrap the text in the columns, and keep the table from exceeding the page width.

However, this results in equally spaced columns, which is not an optimal use of the space of my table, resulting in some cells that are wrapped two or three times, and others that have one word in all that space.

Is there a way to keep a maximum table width, break words, and utilize the browsers layout optimizations for variable width columns?

Comment: `width: 100%` is not fixed width, that is variable width.  Also, can you show the HTML source and styles for the tables TD's?

Comment: If you know which columns are going to need a lower width, you could define for that column header the width. So for example, if column 2 is a thin column, you could say <th style="width: 5%">

Comment: @MikeBrant it is variable width, you are of course correct.  But currently, if the (non-space-broken) data in one of the cells exceeds the width of the containing div, the table extends past the edge of the div and off the page.

Comment: @karancan That was my idea, but it doesn't help if I have two (possibly) wide columns I want to balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a column that you always expect to be larger than the others, you should indicate with e.g. `<td width="40%">`. Also, if there is a column which will always be small, you can set a width to that as well. The more clues you give the browser, the better the layout will look.

Comment: That's what I've started doing, but I've got two columns to balance and using `table-layout: fixed` they're always the same width. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it without losing the browser layout optimizations.